# Can I create a string combining various values of variables (as strings) and pass it as parameter without assigning it first?

Tags: c, string

Take this few lines as an example:

```
char a = 'a';
char b[] = "bc";
char res[2];
sprintf(res, "%c%s", a, b); 
printf("%s", res);
```

What I would like to do is be able to pass the string that the sprintf call saves in res ("abc") to some other function call(printf in this case), without saving it first in res. Or, as an alternative, know how much memory it will take before explicitly writing it in memory so I can first allocate the needed memory(this example doesn't work cause res isn't big enough).
I don't need to use sprintf specifically, just anything that can produce a string combining strings and characters and maybe any other C type.
What's the easiest way to accomplice any of the above, or what's the closest thing I can do?

I'm thinking that I can find the length of the resulting string for a specific sprintf invocation like the one above before executing it because I know the parameters and how they will influence the length of the result string. But in that case I should do different calculations for different calls. Is this the only way?

Comment: You can't. It has to be stored in a variable.

Comment: PSA: `char[2]` holds, *at most*, **one** useful character. To hold `"abc"` you need `char[4]` or bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I create a string combining various values of variables (as strings) and pass it as parameter without assigning it first?

The short answer is: No

Strings in C (aka zero-terminated char arrays) are not passed to a function by passing all individual characters to the function. Instead a pointer to the first character of the string is passed. Consequently, the string must be located somewhere in memory.

When doing stuff like:

```
 some_function("Hello world");
```

it may seem as if "Hello world" is passed without being stored in memory. However, the compiler handled that automatically to make sure that the string (literal) "Hello World" is already somewhere in memory.

When passing a runtime constructed string, it's necessary to save it to memory first.

> Or, as an alternative, know how much memory it will take before explicitly writing it in memory...

Probably not the best performing solution but you can use `snprintf` twice. First time without actually storing the result but just getting the amount of memory required.

```
char a = 'a';
char b[] = "bc";
int required = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%c%s", a, b); // Size is zero to suppress
                                                // writing to buffer

char res[required + 1]; // Here a VLA but could be dynamic allocation instead
sprintf(res, required + 1, "%c%s", a, b); 
printf("%s", res);
```

Based on the answer from @SteveSummit (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75991030/4386427) you can write a function that creates the string and stores it in dynamic allocated memory. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char* dyn_sprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list argp;
    
    // Find size
    va_start(argp, fmt);
    int sz = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, argp);
    va_end(argp);
    
    // Dynamic allocation
    char* buf = malloc(sz + 1); // +1 for termination character
    if (buf == NULL) exit(1);
    
    // Create the string
    va_start(argp, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buf, sz + 1, fmt, argp);
    va_end(argp);
    
    return buf;
}

int main()
{
    char* str;
    
    str= dyn_sprintf("Hello %s%d!", "world", 42);
    puts(str);
    free(str);
    
    str= dyn_sprintf("%.20f-%d-%c-%s!", 3.14, 42, '@', "xyz");
    puts(str);
    free(str);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello world42!
3.14000000000000012434-42-@-xyz!
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard function to do this.
It's reasonably straightforward to implement your own, however.
Here is a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char *ssprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    static char tmpbuf[100];
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, fmt);
    vsnprintf(tmpbuf, 100, fmt, argp);
    va_end(argp);
    return tmpbuf;
}

int main()
{
    char a = 'a';
    char b[] = "bc";
    printf("%s\n", ssprintf("%c%s", a, b));
}
```

Like any function that "wraps" `printf`, this `ssprintf` function must declare a `va_list`, call `va_start` and then call a "v" variant printf function, in this case `vsnprintf`.

And like any function that returns a string, allocating the returned string is problematic.  This implementation takes the quickest, easiest, but cheesiest approach of using a `static` local array.  (By using snprintf, it can at least avoid overflowing the fixed-size buffer, if the caller tries to print something bigger.)

A better approach would be to call `vsnprintf` twice, once to compute the resulting length and once to actually construct it, and then use `malloc` to dynamically allocate a big-enough buffer.
This technique is detailed in [Support Ukraine's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75990898#75992509).
For this technique there is however the problem of deciding when to free the buffer.

Yet another possibility would be to use the nonstandard but very useful [`asprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) function (or in this case you'd actually use `vasprintf`), which automatically allocates a buffer and prints to it.

As mentioned, writing functions that return strings is always problematic in C, due to the subproblem of properly allocating memory for the returned string.  There's probably a canonical SO question on this, or see the C FAQ list, [question 7.5b](https://c-faq.com/malloc/retaggr2.html).

Exercise: For the `ssprintf` function as shown, what happens if you call it twice in a row, and try to print both results, like this?  Why does this happen?

```
printf("%s%s\n",
    ssprintf("%c%d", a, 42),
    ssprintf("%s%f", b, 56.75));
```

Comment: User needs to be aware that repeated use as follows is problematic: `printf("%s %s\n", ssprintf("Hello, %s %d!", "world", 42), ssprintf("Blue, %s %d!", "dog", 33));`

Comment: @jarmod Yes, I meant to mention that.  Done.